# The `aapt` command could not be found, so status bar could not be cleaned…

Tags: android, fastlane

The `aapt` command could not be found, so status bar could not be cleaned. Make sure android_home is configured for screengrab or ANDROID_HOME is set in the environment

I have 'aapt' in the path

```
export PATH=/Users/XXXX/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.2/aapt
```

and I am setting the Android home as

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/XXXX/Library/Android/sdk
```

but while taking screen shots from the device using fastlane command "fastlane Screengrab" I am getting above error. I tried lot ways to fix it .Please help with the suggestions

Comment: Are you getting any other exceptions in the logs below this error?

Comment: The `aapt` command could not be found on your system, so your app APK could not be validated (others all are warning)